# AngularJS: Relative link paths are broken when html5mode(true) is on

Tags: angularjs, relative-path, angular-ui-router, pushstate, location-provider

I've been searching and I've found *"solutions"* to this problem, yet I still can't get this to work right.

## The Scenario:

I'm building an Angular (version 1.2) website with the UI Router and running it on a Node server on localhost. I'm trying to make it have "pretty" url's with the $locationProvider and by turning html5(true) on. My website works fine when clicking through it, but when I try to navigate to a relative link path or refresh the link path the page breaks. I also intend to deploy this webapp to Heroku when completed:

**RELATIVE LINK PATH:**

```
http://localhost:8000/locksmith-services
```

**PAGE OUTPUT RESULT**

```
Cannot GET /locksmith-services
```

## Steps I've taken:

**1.)** In my "index.html" < head >, I've set my base url to:

```
<base href="/"></base>
```

**2.)** In my app.js file (for Angular), I have it written as follows:

```
// App Starts
angular
    .module('app', [
        'ui.router',
        'ngAnimate',
        'angular-carousel'
    ])
    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl'
            })
            .state('services', {
                url: '/locksmith-services',
                templateUrl: 'pages/locksmith-services.html',
                controller: 'servicesCtrl'
            })
            .state('locations', {
                url: '/locksmith-locations',
                templateUrl: 'pages/locksmith-locations.html'
            })
            .state('payment', {
                url: '/locksmith-payment',
                templateUrl: 'pages/locksmith-payment.html'
            })
        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])
```

**3.)** In my navigation, I have my html written as:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a ui-sref="home">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Austin Texas Locksmith" />
    </a>
</div>
<nav class="row navigation">
    <a class="mobile33" ui-sref="services" ui-sref-active="active" class="active">Services</a>
    <a class="mobile33" ui-sref="locations" ui-sref-active="active">Locations</a>
    <a class="mobile33" ui-sref="payment" ui-sref-active="active">Payment</a>
</nav>
```

**4.)** My server.js file (node server)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/front'));
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port);
```

What would be the best solution? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @trehyu for helping me get to this answer.

Like he wrote, I needed something setup on my server.js file that redirects the user to my "index.html" file.

So depending on your file structure...

**BEFORE** (not working)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/front'));
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port);
```

**AFTER** (working)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/front/js'));
app.use('/build', express.static(__dirname + '/../build'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/front/css'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/front/images'));
app.use('/pages', express.static(__dirname + '/front/pages'));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('/front/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port);
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 3):

When HTML5mode is set to true, you need something setup on your server that automatically redirects the user to your index page, so that the AngularJS UI Router can take over from there.

The reason for this is that without the hash (#) in the URL, it takes it as a literal URL and tries to navigate there when you refresh or paste the url directly.

I'm not very familiar with Node so not sure how you would do that, but there is a FAQ page on the UI Router GitHub that should help you get started: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Thankyou for your help! re-writing my server.js file did the trick.