# Redirect all AWS S3 http requests to index.html for AngularJS HTML5Mode

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, html5mode

How do I redirect all requests to my static AWS S3 website to index.html so I can use AngularJS' HTML5 Mode?

I recently learned (to my unending delight) that it is possible to use AngularJS without the `#` in the URL by using [HTML5 Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16678065/5031373).  However, I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26068792/5031373) that this requires some setup on the server, since all requests have to be redirected to the right html file (in this case, `index.html`) for this to work.

I use AWS S3's static website hosting for my site.  I tried adding this to my redirection rules:

```
<RoutingRules>
     <RoutingRule>
         <Redirect>
             <ReplaceKeyWith>/</ReplaceKeyWith>
         </Redirect>
     </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

and

```
<RoutingRules>
     <RoutingRule>
         <Redirect>
             <ReplaceKeyWith>index.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
         </Redirect>
     </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

but I get issues with too many redirects.

Is there a way to do the kind of redirection necessary in AWS S3 with the static website hosting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use AWS CloudFront for your use case. Setup the S3 bucket behind CloudFront and add index.html as the default route.

Still if the page is refreshed in a angular route (e.g /home), AWS CloudFront will search for a /home.html file in S3 and return 404: Not Found Response. However there is a workaround for this, where you can setup an custom error response for 404: Not Found HTTP error code to points towards the /index.html response page path.

[image]

[image]

For more details refer the blog post [Using AWS CloudFront to serve an SPA hosted on S3](https://johnlouros.com/blog/using-CloudFront-to-serve-an-SPA-from-S3).